# iOS - Core Data Stack as singleton with main NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, singleton, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've seen many tutorials and they really help me with understand parent-child managed object context and other things related to this. I am ready to start using it in my app but I have a question. Why nobody use singleton for keeping main managed object context. I guess it would be much better to extract Core Data related objects from AppDelegate and set it to own class right? Something like in this [Tutorial at raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84642/multiple-managed-object-contexts-in-core-data-tutorial). But they still instantiate CoreDataStack class (no problem with this, singleton must be instantiate too) and when it's need they set managedObjectContext in prepareForSegue (and set it to first view controller from AppDelegate). Why not to remove this need and just use singleton CoreDataStack and have possible to use managedObjectContext in each controller if needed?

Second and bonus question: I think it's better to have less code in controller and more in other classes. I think it helps with readability. So what if I move this code from controller and set it for example to CoreDataStack class or some other class that helps with Core Data requests and responses:

```
  func surfJournalFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest =
      NSFetchRequest(entityName: "JournalEntry")
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let sortDescriptor =
      NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest
  }
```

I know it's possible but is it better? If you get app codes from me would it be better if in controller it would be one line `CoreDataStack.fetchRequest("JournalEntry", sortedKey: "date")`?

And what about if I take this code and insert it to singleton and created function with closure? I would created child managed context in singleton and do needed operations in there and in controller I would just changed UI:

```
  func exportCSVFile() {

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = activityIndicatorBarButtonItem()

    let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coreDataStack.context.persistentStoreCoordinator

    privateContext.performBlock { () -> Void in

      var fetchRequestError:NSError? = nil
      let results = privateContext.executeFetchRequest(self.surfJournalFetchRequest(), error: &fetchRequestError)
      if results == nil {
        println("ERROR: \(fetchRequestError)")
      }

      let exportFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "export.csv"
      let exportFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)!
      NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(exportFilePath, contents: NSData(), attributes: nil)

      var fileHandleError: NSError? = nil
      let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: exportFileURL, error: &fileHandleError)
      if let fileHandle = fileHandle {

        for object in results! {
          let journalEntry = object as! JournalEntry

          fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
          let csvData = journalEntry.csv().dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
          fileHandle.writeData(csvData!)
        }

        fileHandle.closeFile()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
          self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
            self.exportBarButtonItem()
          println("Export Path: \(exportFilePath)")
          self.showExportFinishedAlertView(exportFilePath)
        })

      } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
          self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.exportBarButtonItem()
          println("ERROR: \(fileHandleError)")
       })
      }
    }
  }
```

I just want to be sure that my aproach would be okay and would be better than original. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I built my first core data app with a singleton pattern. It seemed logical for me because there is only one core data stack anyway. I was very wrong, the singleton pattern turned into a big mess quickly. I added more and more code to bend the singleton stack to something that works. In the end I gave up and I invested the time to replace the singleton mess with dependency injection.

Here are some of the problems I encountered before I dumped the singleton:

Since the app kept important data, my users requested a backup functionality. To restore from a backup I switched the sqlite file and then I would just create a new Core Data stack. Doing this in a clean way is next to impossible if you use a pull-pattern to get the managedObjectContext from a singleton. So my way to switch the Core Data stack was to tell the user that they have to restart the app. Followed by an `exit()`. Not the most elegant way to handle this.

After Apple added childContexts I decided to get rid of undo managers and context rollbacks, because that never worked 100% for me. But changing my editing viewControllers so they use child contexts which are discarded when the user hits `cancel`, was an incredible painful act because I now had a mix of singleton contexts and viewController local contexts in one viewController.
For editing the targets of relationships I had editViewControllers inside editViewController. Because I created the edit context inside the edit viewControllers I ended up saving data to the main context that shouldn't have been saved. It's a bit complicated to explain, but the second viewController saved stuff like new objects to the main context even if the user in the outer edit viewController hit cancel. Which always lead to orphaned objects. So I added more code to bend the singleton in a way that would make it less of a singleton.

I also had a CSV import function and I wanted to preview the data to the user before they press "Import". I build a totally new infrastructure for that. First I parsed the CSV into a data structure that basically duplicated my core data classes. Then I build a viewController to display these non core data classes, with even more code duplication. I would only start to create core data objects when the user pressed import.
After I got rid of the singleton pattern I could reuse the existing data display viewController. I would just give it a different context, in this case an in-memory context that contained the data that will be imported. Much cleaner, less duplicated code.

I guess some of these problems were not really the singletons fault. I was just very inexperienced.
But I still would strongly recommend against singleton core data.

---

> would be one line `CoreDataStack.fetchRequest("JournalEntry", sortedKey: "date")`?

You don't need a singleton for this. Stuff like this should be in the NSManagedObject subclass you create for JournalEntry.

---

> And what about if I take this code and insert it to singleton and created function with closure? I would created child managed context in singleton and do needed operations in there and in controller I would just changed UI:

And why don't you create a method that doesn't require internal state at all?

```
class func export(#context: NSManagedObjectContext, toCSVAtPath path: String, 
                  progress: ((current: Int, totalCount: Int) -> Void)?,
                completion: ((success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void)?) {
```

Much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer. I discard the idea with singleton and I would use strong properties for managed object context. You're right with fetchRequest and it would make more sense in NSManagedObject. The last method you suggest looks good but what context should be as parameter? Private or main? Last example I post mainly because I wasn't sure if is good to move these kind of methods (more complicated, ...) to other classes (it's better for readability and reuse). If move how to deal with private MOC. If create outside method or inside. What's better for ARC and threads?